# ASP.Net Store User Password in Session cookie?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

I know the Membership provider stores the user name and an expiration time in an encrypted cookie and then uses that to verify the user is still logged in for a session.

Would it be possible to store the users password in this encrypted cookie as well. If so how would you access it server side?

I need the users username and password available server side because I need to call web services that use those same credentials. Is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should store it in session state, which never leaves the server.

You should also try to change those web services to use authentication tickets instead of passwords (eg, OAuth), because it's never a good idea to store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Would I save them into the session state as the user was first authenticated? How do you make sure the membership session expires at the same time as the session state? I would need them to stay in sync I believe.

Comment: @metalideath - Yes, store them as soon as you're able to. If the session ends, either by the user clearing their cookies (and thus losing any reference to their session) or the server timing out the session, you'll need to re-authenticate the user and restore the password in the session again.

Comment: @metalideath: Only if you put it in SQL Server (which is not a good idea for a password)

Comment: Well then I am thinking session state will not work for me. I need a scalable solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that. You pass the encoded info in the userData field of the FormsAuthenticationTicket constructor:

```
  FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(version,
    name, issueDate, expirationDate, isPersistent, yourEncodedData);
  string secureTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
  Response.Cookies.Add(
      new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, secureTicket));
```

Ideally, this should be done over an SSL connection, and the ticket cookie should be marked with both the HttpOnly and Secure attributes.

Then, to retrieve the value:

```
FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)User.Identity;
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;
string yourEncodedInfo = ticket.UserData;
```

You could also just set your own cookie, separate from the forms auth ticket.

However, storing a password directly in a cookie, even if encrypted, is not a good idea from a security perspective. Instead, use Session state:

```
Session["password"] = password;
```

Session state also uses a cookie, but the cookie itself only contains a key. The server uses the key to obtain a dictionary of key/value pairs unique to that session, which stay on the server (or get serialized to the DB, depending on how it's configured).

Comment: Thanks for an example of using the session state, +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended but you can use [FormsAuthenticationTicket.UserData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata.aspx).

Comment: As far as I can tell isn't that the same thing SLaks is recommending? I don't really understand the difference between the membership provided session and the "session state". Maybe there is no difference and that is what is confusing me.

Comment: @metalideath. The Session Cookie is very different than Forms Authentication Cookie. Read the "Forms Authentication" chapter of Stefan Schackow book for complete understanding.

Comment: @metalideath: This goes directly into the forms auth cookie  on the client.  I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I don't understand why its not recommended. The cookie is AES encrypted so its secure. Does this somehow make server scaling harder to accomplish?

Comment: @metalideath, This is correct that ASP.NET AUTH cookie is both encrypted and validated(signed). So it will almost impossible to create these type of tickets. But If somehow user become able to decrypt this ticket, then he will become aware of your userid/password which is baddest situation ever you can think. So, be careful. See the suggestion ASP.NET team member suggestion in version 1.0 time. http://forums.asp.net/t/326633.aspx/1. Also, there is some limitation for using UserData. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata%28v=vs.90%29.aspx